# Spring Boot set content type and charset using HTTPHeaders for XML

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using the `HttpHeaders` in Spring Boot to set the content type and charset for a JSON response using:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
```

Which then returns the header: `Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8`

But the closet I can get with XML is `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);`

Which gives me the header: `Content-Type →application/xml`

How can I go about including the charset in the content type for XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add header

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Reference document:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding

Helpful link:  https://coderanch.com/t/585940/frameworks/setting-content-type-json-response#3318471